# Get files from no_backup folder

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, storage

I need get files from no_backup folder in my production app - I can't lose these files.

In Android Studio (file explorer) that folder has path:
*data/data/com.package.name/no_backup/my_files_list*

Is there way to do this?

Phone is OnePlus 8 Pro - I have that device and I can do everything, but any file explorer from google play cannot find this folder, android studio can see that folder when my app is in debbug, but I can't run debugg app because my installed app will be uninstaled and "no_backup" folder will be lost.

Comment: Your app itself can copy these files to a storage location that remains after uninstall of the app. I wonder who put files in no_backup folder as you did not tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this path is pointing on system partition. if you want to copy these files programmatically you have to get root access (or at least use privileged/preinstalled system app). if your device isn't rooted (rooting most oftenly wipes data/factory reset) and there is no default/system file explorer with viewing OS partition feature (never seen installed by default, thats would be very insecure) then you won't get access to these files

Comment: If I understand - these files I can get only if I can rooted device, but if I want to root that device - I'll wipes data and I'll lost that app with files? So isn't way to get these files?

Comment: looks like there is no way sadly... look for a way for rooting your device without data wiping, but afaik 99% of rooting ways/devices are being wiped then (no suprise, thats for security purposes)